# Guidance Automation Extensions for VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, scsf

In our project, we using GAX for making SCSF Templates, until now we used visual studio 2015,
today we upgraded our development environment and started to use Vs 2017, I tried to search for a proper version for GAX but without success, there is one that I can download or we stack?

maybe there is an alternative way that similar to cab architecture for creating a WinForms application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found half solution for my problem, ..

Thanks to johnx7271 that upgrade the GAT/GAX that will work with Visual Studio 2017 - [LINK](https://github.com/johnx7271/OpenGAX)

but I still stuck with adding SCSF templates (found only until vs 2015)